# NativeScript with Angular: SASS file is not transpiled

Tags: angular, sass, nativescript

I use the TabView template generated by NativeScript Sidekick - each tab is a component in its own folder below the TabView component. Now I added following SASS files to them:

```
@Component({
selector: "Search",
moduleId: module.id,
templateUrl: "./search.component.html",
styleUrls: ["./search.component.css"]
```

})

with SASS file "_search.component.scss"

and

```
@Component({
selector: "Browse",
moduleId: module.id,
templateUrl: "./browse.component.html",
styleUrls: ["./browse.component.css"]
```

})

with SASS file "_browse.component.scss".

Now the search.component.css is generated (was the 1st one I added) - but I did not manage to get the browse.component.css generated (Android). I tried cleaning, deleting build folder several name - without any success. 
What could be the reason for this?